# How to properly ground chassis containing AC/DC switching power supply?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, grounding, dac

I'm planning to build a Digital Audio Converter as a hobby device and I had some questions regarding safely grounding the chassis.

I want to purchase a power supply like this one:

MicroMall(TM) NEW Universal Regulated Switching Power Supply DC 5V 3A 15W

[image: MicroMall(TM) NEW Universal Regulated Switching Power Supply DC 5V 3A 15W]

and place it inside a metal chassis. I'm going to ground the power supply to the earth ground. I want to minimize any interference with the audio output (RCA jacks in the case).

I have a couple questions:

1) should the V- of the DC circuit be connected to the earth ground?

2) How can I ground the external chassis?

Comment: Unfortunatelly effectiveness of safety ground and EMI grounding didn't go together.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, don't connect V- to earth ground.
2. Connect the ground pin (left on -V) to earth ground, the green wire of the line cord.

Comment: 3. Connect the enclosing metal chassis of the hobby device also to earth ground, the green wire of the line cord (isn't that green-yellow everywhere?)

Comment: Theres at least two color codes for flexible appliance cords still in use. The american code uses black for live, white for neutral and green for earth. The european "harmonised" code uses brown for live, blue for neutral and green/yellow for earth.